# YOLOv8 inference with OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, yolo, yolov8

I have trined YOLOv8 model for segmentation on a custom dataset, the model can do inference successfully when loaded by ultralytics, however I would like to run it on edge device for which ultralytics would be a bit heavy to install. Therefore I am using opencv.
I have exported my model to onnx format using the command:

```
my_new_model.export(format='onnx', imgsz=[800,800], opset=12)
```

and then when I try to load the model with OpenCV and do inference (using this [code](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/examples/YOLOv8-OpenCV-ONNX-Python/main.py))
While I have 3 classes only, this part of the code below(from the link I mentioned) will print{2, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 24}, while It should give only a set of {0,1,2} as I have 3 classes. I am just confused where do these numbers came from.
My classes are defined as:

CLASSES = ['lemon', 'tomato', 'watermelon']

```
for i in range(rows):
    classes_scores = outputs[0][i][4:]
    (minScore, maxScore, minClassLoc, (x, maxClassIndex)) = cv2.minMaxLoc(classes_scores)
    if maxScore >= 0.25:
        box = [
            outputs[0][i][0] - (0.5 * outputs[0][i][2]), outputs[0][i][1] - (0.5 * outputs[0][i][3]),
            outputs[0][i][2], outputs[0][i][3]]
        boxes.append(box)
        scores.append(maxScore)
        class_ids.append(maxClassIndex)

result_boxes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, scores, 0.25, 0.45, 0.5)
print(set(class_ids))
```

Note that I have changed the number 640 in the code they provided since my model is trained and exported for images with size 800x800

Comment: The inference [code](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/examples/YOLOv8-OpenCV-ONNX-Python/main.py) you have provided is for the detection task model, not for the segmentation one. Maybe this code for [segmentation on ONNXRuntime](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/tree/main/examples/YOLOv8-Segmentation-ONNXRuntime-Python) will do the job.

Comment: Thank you, my intent was to avoid installing ultralytics on the edge device, and load the model just with onnx-runtime and opencv. on github the codes ultralytics provides for segmentation and object counting require installing their library while the code for detections does not. I just want to have the same but for object counting.